# Has anyone tried developing Washi S film (B&W ISO50 ) with Ilfosol 3 developer (Ilford product)?

Tags: film

I am new here. I would like advice about how to develop Washi S film at ISO50 using Ilfosol 3. I cannot find this combination anywhere. In the film datasheet it is only reported with Ilfotec lc29 1:20 12min. I intend to develop it by Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems to be a specialist film, I would suggest that you develop it using a developer recommended by the manufacturer. You could always contact Lomography and ask them about the suitability of Ilfosol 3.